# How do I get the properties on a class that extends object?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to save some settings, to do so, I'm trying to list the properties of a class, but I get 0.

```
package
{
public class Definitions extends Object
{
    var _userDevicePhone: Boolean = true;
    var _userDeviceTablette: Boolean = false;
    var _userDeviceDesktop: Boolean = false;
    var _userDeviceLock: Boolean = false;

    var stages: Object;
    var objectTransform: Object;
    var editorGrid: Object;
    var navigator: Object;

    public function Definitions()
    {}
    function Init(): void
    {
        trace("initialising definitions");
        stages = Main.stages;
        objectTransform = Main.objectTransform;
        editorGrid = Main.editorGrid;
        navigator = Main.navigator;
    }
}
}

package
{
public class UserSettings
{
    var definitions: Object;

    public function UserSettings()
    {}
    function Init(): void
    {
        definitions = Main.definitions;
    }
    function Save(): void
    {
        var cnt: int;
        for (var s: String in definitions)
        {
            cnt++;
            //var value: Object = definitions[i];
            //trace(i + " = " + value);
        }
        trace(cnt);
    }
}
}
```

I've cut out huge portions of code here, but I think what remains is enough to understand my problem... it traces 0. I'm new to all this, I thought that a class was an object, I even extended object on the definitions class, maybe I did not understand what it does. Please help!

Comment: The **for..in** loop iterates over dynamic keys while omitting non-dynamic (predefined) properties. If you want to learn the instance structure at runtime, you need to use the **describeType(...)** method: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType() Otherwise, if you just want to trace the existing properties, make a list of their names.

Comment: I sense a XY problem here. With statically defined classes you always know the number of properties an instance of a class has. With `dynamic` classes such as `Object` this approach should really return the proper number.